# Deferred Shadow Mapping GLSL

Tags: opengl, mapping, glsl, shadow, deferred

Im currently implementing a deferred rendering pipeline and im stuck with shadow mapping. 
Ive already implemented it succesfully into a forward pipeline.

The Steps i do are:

1. Get Position in Light View
2. Convert to light view clip space
3. Get shadow tex coords with * 0.5 + 0.5;
4. check depth

**Edit: Updated code with new result image:**

```
float checkShadow(vec3 position) {
// get position in light view
mat4 invView = inverse(cameraView);
vec4 pEyeDir =  sunBias * sunProjection  * sunView * invView  * vec4(position, 1.0);

// light view clip space
pEyeDir = pEyeDir / pEyeDir.w;

// get uv coordinates
vec2 sTexCoords = pEyeDir.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;

float bias = 0.0001;
float depth = texture(sunDepthTex, sTexCoords).r - bias;
float shadow = 1.0f;

if(pEyeDir.z * 0.5 + 0.5 > depth)
{
    shadow = 0.3f;
}

return shadow;
```

}

here some variables important for the code above:

```
vec3 position = texture(positionTex, uv).rgb;
```

Also i get a dark background( meshes stay the same) at some camera positions, only happens when i multiply the shadow value to the final color.

[image]

As requested, here are the position and sun depth texture:

[image: position]
[image: shadow depth]

Comment: some images to show?? what syncronicity..:-)

Comment: at first sight, it's strange that you use eye vector to compute shadowTexCoord. it's should be computed with `translate(0.5,0.5) * scale(0.5,0.5) * lightProj * lightView * vertexPos` - ( modelTransformations * vertexPos)

Comment: the image you see is the result of NOT using the eye vector. i used only the position from the position texture. Is the objects model matrix needed? isnt that what the gbuffer position texture is for?

Comment: `vec4 ModWorldPos =  inverse(gl_ModelViewMatrix) * gl_Vertex - inverse(modelView) * gl_Vertex ; 
ShadowCoord= gl_TextureMatrix[7] * (gl_Vertex - ModWorldPos);` here is mine, texture matrix is `translate(0.5,0.5) * scale(0.5,0.5) * lightProj * lightView`

Comment: are you sure you use deferred rendering? i dont know how i should pass each model matrix to the deferred pass, as this is only a shaded quad. And you use deprecated glsl functions like glTextureMatrix. i use 4.2 core.

Comment: effectively, it's not deffered, sorry. Never played with deffered shadow mapping...

Comment: well thanks for the try anyway, but my problem is with the position handling using deferred shadow mapping. got it working in forward rendering myself :)

Comment: can you show raw positionTex and shadowTex?

Comment: @j-p i uploaded them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i fixed it. The problem was because the light depth had a different size than the gbuffer textures.

To use different texture sizes i had to normalize them with

```
coords = (coords / imageSize ) * windowSize;
```